# How can I get the top row out of the following data in sas using proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Dataset a:-

```
cc dob enrolled

1 10-13-1981 10-13-2001 

2 10-17-1984 12-15-2004 

3 07-20-1957 12-20-2007 

4 10-13-1989 12-24-2010 

5 10-13-1996 12-28-2013 

6 10-14-1996 12-11-1999 

7 10-15-1996 12-24-2010 

8 10-16-1996 12-24-2010 

9 10-17-1996 12-24-2010 

10 10-18-1996 12-24-2010
```

**SAS Code:-**

```
proc sql;

select distinct count(*) as cust_enrolled ,year(enrolled) as yr

from a 

group by yr

order by cust_enrolled desc;

quit;
```

**Result:-**

```
cust_enrolled yr 

5 2010 

1 2013 

1 2004 

1 1999 

1 2001 

1 2007
```

My query is to get the first row from this result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this SQL dialect support `LIMIT 1` after your `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Do you want only the first observation or do you want all of the years that have the maximum number of observations.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would use a `having` clause testing an aggregate such as `freq=max(freq)`.  However, since `freq` is already an aggregate `count(*)` that has to be in a sub-select.

Example:

```
data have;
input cc dob: mmddyy10. enrolled: mmddyy10.;
format dob enrolled mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1 10-13-1981 10-13-2001 
2 10-17-1984 12-15-2004 
3 07-20-1957 12-20-2007 
4 10-13-1989 12-24-2010 
5 10-13-1996 12-28-2013 
6 10-14-1996 12-11-1999 
7 10-15-1996 12-24-2010 
8 10-16-1996 12-24-2010 
9 10-17-1996 12-24-2010 
10 10-18-1996 12-24-2010 
;
proc sql;
  create table most_popular_enrollment_year as
  select * from 
  (select count(*) as freq, year(enrolled) as yr_enroll
   from have
   group by yr_enroll
  ) 
  having freq=max(freq)
  ;
quit;
```

If there are multiple years with the max number of  year enrollment count the query will return multiple rows.  If you want the earliest year of those you need another nesting.

```
proc sql;
  create table earliest_most_popular as
  select * from 
    (
      select * from 
      (
        select count(*) as freq, year(enrolled) as yr_enroll
        from have
        group by yr_enroll
      ) 
      having freq=max(freq)
    )
    having yr_enroll=min(yr_enroll)
  ;
quit;
```

Another way is to sort by `yr_enroll` and use Proc SQL option `OUTOBS=1` to grab the first

```
proc sql outobs=1;
  create table earliest_most_popular as
  select * from 
  (
    select count(*) as freq, year(enrolled) as yr_enroll
    from have
    group by yr_enroll
  ) 
  having freq=max(freq)
  order by yr_enroll
  ;
  reset outobs=max;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTOBS option of PROC SQL to control how many observations the SELECT statement writes to the output destination(s).

First let's convert your listing into an actual dataset.

```
data have;
  input cc dob :mmddyy. enrolled :mmddyy.;
  format dob enrolled date9.;
datalines;
1  10-13-1981 10-13-2001 
2  10-17-1984 12-15-2004 
3  07-20-1957 12-20-2007 
4  10-13-1989 12-24-2010 
5  10-13-1996 12-28-2013 
6  10-14-1996 12-11-1999 
7  10-15-1996 12-24-2010 
8  10-16-1996 12-24-2010 
9  10-17-1996 12-24-2010 
10 10-18-1996 12-24-2010 
;
```

Now let's run your SELECT statement with OUTOBS set to 1.  Make sure to give it some criteria for deciding which observation to take when there are ties for the largest count.

```
proc sql outobs=1;
select year(enrolled) as yr
     , count(*) as cust_enrolled
from have
group by yr
order by cust_enrolled desc, yr
;
quit;
```

Results:

```
                 cust_
      yr      enrolled
----------------------
    2010             5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data set options anywhere. SQL doesn't guarantee an order so you often will want logic that's more complicated than simply the first, but if that's what you want using the `OBS=1` option is a decent option.

```
proc sql;
select * from sashelp.class(obs=1);
quit;
```

If you want something besides the first, use `FIRSTOBS` and `OBS` together.

```
proc sql;
select * from sashelp.class(firstobs=10 obs=10);
quit;
```